# Angular 6 lazy loading ngOnInit occurs before DOM drawn?

Tags: angular

So something has broken in my code and in my attempt to debug the issue, I'm backtracking through our current check-ins and seeing that lazy loading on route selection was implemented.

Previously, on ngOnInit() I was using nativeElement.clientWidth and clientHeight to determine the placement of some items on the page, but after lazy loading was implemented, on ngOnInit() clientWidth and clientHeight are both 0.

So I'm guessing our code is firing before the DOM is being drawn. Is this how lazy loading is supposed to work? If so, how do I work around this?

Comment: use ngAfterViewInit life cycle hook

Answer (score 1):

The `ngOnInit` lifecycle hook is actually the first `ngOnChanges` and fires before the DOM gets rendered, it's by design and you can figure it out by placing a `debugger;` into it.

If you want to compute something based on the rendered page, then you need to use the `ngAfterViewInit` lifecycle hook

Comment: Doesn't seem to fix the issue. The height and width are still 0. Even looking at the computed css show height and width to be 0. I guess it is something else.